# haproxy redirect with/without trailing slash, with parameters

Tags: dictionary, redirect, haproxy

Target:

Config on HaProxy 1.5.18, to redirect:

```
/path1 --> /path2/
/path1/ --> /
/path1?parameter1=somevalue/ -- > /
```

Here is config segment:

```
acl is_root path -i /
acl missing_slash path_reg ^/*/[^/]*$$
http-request redirect location %[capture.req.uri,map(/etc/haproxy/redirect.map)] code 301 if { capture.req.uri,map(/etc/haproxy/redirect.map) -m beg }
http-request redirect code 301 prefix / append-slash if missing_slash !is_root
```

map file:

```
/path1    /path2/
```

Here is behavior:

```
/path1 --> /path2/
/path1/ --> /
/path1?parameter1=somevalue/ --> Error page:
    This page isn’t working this.domain.org redirected you too many times.
    Try clearing your cookies.
    ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

The only trouble here is, url with parameters cannot redirect to /. Any hint to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: The correct regex seems like it should be `path_reg [^/]$` (ends with any character that is not `/`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a special reason for using this particular regex, to make sure all referred css/js etc files working, otherwise the css files will be missed. Right now, the only trouble is, it cannot redirect when url has params.

Comment: I have got the solution. Using separate ACLs and avoid appending / for those URLs have params.